# Laravel Unique validation on checking multiple fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have `subject` tables and fields are `standard_id`, `stream_id`, `medium_id`, `board_id`, `subject_name` and many others.

I want to add Rule unique for `subject_name` which is unique for `standard_id`, `stream_id`, `medium_id`, `board_id` fields.

```
$validator = Validator::make( $inputs, 
            [
                'v_name' => [
                        'required',
                        Rule::unique( 'tbl_subject' )->ignore( $id, 'id' ),
                    ],
            ],
            [
                'v_name.required' => 'Name is required',
                'unique' => 'Name address already exits.',
            ]
        );
```

Example

`standard_id`, `stream_id`, `medium_id`, `board_id` `subject_name`

```
1             2            1            3          A
3             2            4            1          B
1             3            1            4          c
```

Validation like if subject_name "A" unique for 1, 2, 1, 3. B unique for 3, 2, 4, 1.
But subject_name "A" not unique for 2,2,1,3 and so on..

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far and how it doesn't match what you need.

Comment: So for example it would fail if you got a `subject_name`  of `A` for the `1, 2, 1, 3` combination of inputs? Are those inputs in your request as well? Try implementing something like what is mentioned in [Adding additional where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: You using Form Requests? Or validating in controller?

Comment: @KurtFriars Validation in controller.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya Can you please share the code where you are validating

Comment: @KurtFriars I updated my answer. i know how unique work in single fields but do not know for this criteria

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya I believe you can still use the $validator->after in my code below directly in your controller. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: @KurtFriars I will try form request. Thanks

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya I meant you can copy/paste it into your controller using the $validator you created. But I think FormRequests are the best choice if you want to do validation. Encapsulates it nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*** After discussion with OP ***

The question should have stated that they are trying to insert a single record, and want to verify the uniqueness against the database. One way to do this is via a [custom rule](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules), like so:

```
class UniqueSubject implements Rule
{
    private $keys;

    public function __construct(array $keys) {
        $this->keys = $keys;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return ! Subject::where($this->keys)->where('subject_name', $value)->exists();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The Subject Name must be unique for the given standard, stream, medium and board.';
    }
}
```

Then you can use the validation in your rules like:

```
$keys = $request->only('i_standard_id', 'i_stream_id', 'i_board_id', 'i_medium_id');

$validator = Validator::make( $inputs, [
    ...
    'subject_name' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        new UniqueSubject($keys)
    ],
    ...
]);
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218089/discussion-between-amit-senjaliya-and-kurt-friars).